# Make WordPress "readonly" on a given site

Tags: migration

I'm moving a WordPress installation from one server to another. The IP 
address will change, but the URL will not, since I will redirect DNS.

The problem: while DNS changes propogate, people might end up at 
either installation.

That's fine for reading, but if they leave comments/register/etc on 
the old server, their comments/registration/etc will be lost.

Is there any way I can make WordPress "read only" on the old site?

I realize WordPress uses its database (MySQL in my case) for internal 
purposes, and I can't simply disallow database writes.

In other words, I want to disallow user-initiated database 
writes/changes, but nothing that will stop WordPress for working 
properly in read-only mode.

Ideally, each page on the old server would say something like:

"You are viewing this WordPress blog on an old server. Until you 
receive a DNS update with a new IP address for wordpress.foo.com, you 
can read articles, but cannot comment on articles, register as a new 
user, etc".

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/780/creating-a-static-website-based-on-a-wordpress-website)? Is it an option?

Answer (score 1):

Turn off commenting in your old blog using the following Plugin
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/disable-comments/

Then turn off the new user registration from Settings->General by unchecking "Anyone can register"

Hope it will help :)

Comment: I'd add as suggestion to redirect all users (but the main admin) to the frontend if they try to log in the backend.

Comment: that's a good addition, too :)

Comment: Here it is: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/22357/12615 ;)